# Add a condition inside the HoverIntent function

Tags: jquery, hover, visibility, hoverintent

I use the hoverintent plug in, for detect a intent hover on a menu. 
http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html

```
  $( "#menu li a").stop().hoverIntent({

     sensitivity: 3, // number = sensitivity threshold (must be 1 or higher)
     interval: 60,  // number = milliseconds of polling interval

     over: function () {
        ... the submenu category appears....
     }
});
```

In this example, this create a 60 milliseconds delay before launching the function.
But when a submenu is already open, i don't wanna have this 60" delay.
So, i try to set the interval to 0 if .hovermenu is visible.
And set it to 60 if .hovermenu is visible.

I have try to add some condition if/else like this :

```
if ($(".hovermenu").css("visibility") == "hidden") {
   interval: 60, 
} else {
    interval: 0, 
}
```

EDIT : Here is a jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/fgfjn/4/
IN this Js fiddle, the start interval is set to 300ms for highlight the effect.

But it doesn't work... I've try many way, but i don't find the solution...
Many thanks if you have an idea !

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle

Comment: Thanks USB :) I'm trying, but it don't understand why the classic hoverIntent doesnt work in jsfiddle... I'm on it currently... If you have an advice : http://jsfiddle.net/fgfjn/

Comment: The jsfiddle works : it's here : http://jsfiddle.net/fgfjn/1/

Comment: can you be more clear what your problem is in the fiddle?

Comment: I have update the jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/fgfjn/4/ My goal is that the first hover has the HoverIntent effect. But if survol menu is open, i want to set the interval to 0, and have a classic hover effect. Thanks !

Comment: Sorry but i am still not getting you. What do you want to say by `classic hover effect.`

Comment: With HoverIntent, you can set the interval : The action start after an interval. I try to have a condition who says : If .survolmenu is visible, set the interval of hoverintent to 0, if .survolmenu is invisible, set the interval of hoverIntent to 60. Thank you :)

Comment: there is no external API to change options on the fly. The whole plugin is not a lot of code. You will need to modify the plugin to accept passing options in to change the internal value of interval on the fly. For a template on how to make those modifications the `plugin authoring guide` on jquery docs site has just what you need.

Comment: Thanks Charlietfl. Maybe it will be easier to just add a delay to a classic Jquery hover :)